# Unable to locate an element which have dynamic id

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to locate an element but the id changes every time.

This is the HTML code for the same :

```
<a id="A7632AF8-BE67-4AEA-9621-437B54235111" target="K2MenuSystemMainFrame" title="New Second Level Menu Item" href="https://thehubtest.cargill.com/Runtime/Runtime/Form/TheHub.TemplateDistribution/" onclick="desele"/>
```

Comment: What did you tried so far ? Are you asking about element with dynamic ID  or you are not able to locate this element at all or getting any error ?

Comment: i am not able to locate this element

Comment: can you update the code in your question  how did you tried

Comment: Thread.Sleep(6000);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("A5D45A48-1327-4782-835E-5825231A6A37")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[contains(@title,'New Second Level Menu Item')]")).Click();

Comment: Try this xpath and let me know if any issue `//a[@title='New Second Level Menu Item']`

Comment: Again i m getting error.. Value can not be converted to specified type

Comment: Which error . can you post complete stacktrace

Comment: Result StackTrace: 
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByXPath(String xpath)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClasse.<XPath>b__c(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use following xpath :

```
Xpath=//a[contains(@href,'https://thehubtest.cargill.com/Runtime/Runtime/Form/TheHub.TemplateDistribution/')]
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException : Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//*[contains(@title,'New Second Level Menu Item')] because of the following error:
Error: bad token: 'New Second Level Menu Item'

Answer (score 0):

try this
Xpath=//a[contains(@title,'New Second Level Menu Item')]
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can write css locators with the help of string matches.

> ^= Match a prefix

```
css=a[target^='K2MenuSystem']
or
css=a[title^='New Second']
or
css=a[href^='https://thehubtest.cargill.com']
```

> $= Match a suffix

```
css=a[target$='MainFrame']
or
css=a[title$='Level Menu Item']
```

> *= Match a substring

```
css=a[target*='SystemMain']
```